# How to support multiple type parameters in wrapped Query method in Dapper (using DapperWrapper)?

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

We're using the [DapperWrapper](https://github.com/half-ogre/dapper-wrapper) classes to extend and wrap the Dapper IDbConnection interface in order to support testing our repository layer. However, we've run into an issue when trying to use the parent/child mapping support in Dapper to map multiple resultsets in our query back to hierarchical objects, as shown in the ParentChildIdentityAssociations example test here:

https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Tests/Tests.cs#L1443

So this feature is supported by Dapper, but it seems that support for multiple type parameters is lost when we use the IDbExecutor in DapperWrapper. When I try to do the following, I get a compile error "Incorrect number of type parameters."

```cs
var results = Db.Query<Deal, DealOption, Deal>(template.RawSql, template.Parameters).FirstOrDefault();
```

The following sample from DapperWrapper illustrates the method we're actually calling and the enclosed SqlConnection object (extended with Dapper). Is there a reason why the original SqlConnection/IDbConnection object would support multiple type parameters defined by T, while the wrapping method defined the same way would not?

```cs
public IEnumerable<T> Query<T>(
    string sql, 
    object param = null,
    IDbTransaction transaction = null,
    bool buffered = true,
    int? commandTimeout = default(int?),
    CommandType? commandType = default(CommandType?))
{
    return _sqlConnection.Query<T>(
    sql, 
    param,
    transaction,
    buffered,
    commandTimeout,
    commandType);
}
```